InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant
0
I am trying to use an Azure compute cluster and I am trying to build an environment as part of the process with the below code snippet.
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# import required libraries for environments examples

from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment, BuildContext

# Enter details of your Azure Machine Learning workspace

subscription_id = "\<The subscription_id \>"
resource_group = "The resource_group "
workspace = "The workspace"

# connect to the workspace

ml_client = MLClient(
DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace,
)

env_docker_conda = Environment(
image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/curated/acpt-pytorch-2.1-cuda12.1:10",
conda_file="/path to conda env file",
name="name of env",
description="description of env",
)
ml_client.environments.create_or_update(env_docker_conda)

I get the following error (from the last line) when I run it:
azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError: (InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant) The access token is from the wrong issuer ' https://sts.windows.net/33e01921-4d64-4f8c-a055-5bdaffd5e33d/'. It must match the tenant ' https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) ' https://login.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later.
I have tried the following so far
az login --tenant 'The tenant id' az account set --subscription 'The subscription id' in azure cli and also set os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']="My tenant id"
The authority (URL) in the error message leads to a page not found page.

You have to login from the account the where you application registered.
I have tried to login using InteractiveBrowserCredential with my personal account got the same error.

Restart the kernal in the notebook and try InteractiveBrowserCredential like below.
ml_client = MLClient(
    InteractiveBrowserCredential(),
    "subscription_id", 
    "resource_group", 
    "jgsml"
)

then choose the correct account where your application registered.
If you are using correct account and still facing then make sure that the Azure subscription you're trying to access is associated with the correct Azure Active Directory tenant.
